# Debug a DOMDocument Object in PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to debug a large and complex DOMDocument object in php.  Ideally it'd be nice if I could get DOMDocument to output in a array-like format.

DoMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>");
var_dump($dom); //or something equivalent
```

This outputs

```
DOMDocument Object ( )
```

whereas I'd like it to output

```
DOMDocument:
html
=>body
==>p
===>Hello World
```

Or something like that.  Why is there no handy debug or output for this?!?

Answer (score 36):

This answer is a little late probably, but I liked your question!

PHP has nothing build-in directly to solve your problem, so there is not XML dump or something.

However, PHP has the [`RecursiveTreeIterator`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/RecursiveTreeIterator) that comes pretty close to your output:

```
\-<html>
  \-<body>
    \-<p>
      \-Hello World
```

(it will look better if your X(HT)ML structure looks more complicated.)

It's used quite simple (as most iterators) with a `foreach`:

```
$tree = new RecursiveTreeIterator($iterator);
foreach($tree as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value . "\n";
}
```

(You can wrap this inside a function, so you only need to call the function)

Even this looks simple, there's one caveat: it needs a `RecursiveIterator` over the `DOMDocument` tree. As PHP can not guess what you need, it needs to be wrapped into code. As written, I found the question interesting (and obviously you have not asked for XML output), so I wrote some little code that offers the recursive iterator needed. So here we go.

First of all you might not be familiar with iterators in PHP. That's no deal to make use of the code I'll show as I'll do it *backwards*, however, whenever you consider to run some code on your own, consider whether or not you can make use of the iterator capabilities PHP has to offer. I write that because it helps to solve common problems and to make components that are not really related with each other to work with each other. For example, the [`RecursiveTreeIterator`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/RecursiveTreeIterator) is built-in, and it will work with anything you feed it with (and you can even configure it). However it needs a `RecursiveIterator` to operate upon.

So let's give it a `RecursiveIterator` that offers `<tag>` for `DOMNodes` that are tags (elements) and just the `text` if they are textnodes:

```
class DOMRecursiveDecoratorStringAsCurrent extends RecursiveIteratorDecoratorStub
{
    public function current()
    {
        $node = parent::current();
        $nodeType = $node->nodeType;

        switch($nodeType)
        {
            case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
                return "<$node->tagName>";

            case XML_TEXT_NODE:
                return $node->nodeValue;

            default:
                return sprintf('(%d) %s', $nodeType, $node->nodeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This `DOMRecursiveDecoratorStringAsCurrent` class (the name is exemplary only) makes use of some abstract code in `RecursiveIteratorDecoratorStub`. The important part however is the `::current` function which just returns the `tagName` of a `DOMNode` in [brackets<sup>*Wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) (`<>`) and the text of textnodes as-is. That's what your output needs, so that's everything needed to code.

Actually this does not work until you have the abstract code as well, but to visualize the code how it's used (the most interesting part), let's view it:

```
$iterator = new DOMRecursiveDecoratorStringAsCurrent($iterator);
$tree = new RecursiveTreeIterator($iterator);
foreach($tree as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value . "\n";
}
```

As it's done backwards, for the moment we have the output specified based on which `DOMNode` is to be displayed by the `RecursiveTreeIterator`. Fine so far, easy to get. But the missing meat it is inside the abstract code and how to create a `RecursiveIterator` over all nodes inside a `DOMElement`. Just preview the whole code how it is invoked (as written before, you can put this into a function to make it easily accessible within your code for debugging purposes. Probably a function called `xmltree_dump`):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>");
$iterator = new DOMRecursiveIterator($dom->documentElement);
$iterator = new DOMRecursiveDecoratorStringAsCurrent($iterator);
$tree = new RecursiveTreeIterator($iterator);
foreach($tree as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value . "\n";
}
```

So what do we got here in addition to the code already covered? First there is a `DOMRecursiveIterator` - and that's it. The rest of the code is standard `DOMDocument` code.

So let's write about `DOMRecursiveIterator`. It's the needed `RecursiveIterator` that's finally needed within the `RecursiveTreeIterator`. It get's *decorated* so that the dump of the tree actually prints tagnames in brackets and text as-is.

Probably it's worth to share the code of it now:

```
class DOMRecursiveIterator extends DOMIterator implements RecursiveIterator
{
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return $this->current()->hasChildNodes();
    }
    public function getChildren()
    {
        $children = $this->current()->childNodes;
        return new self($children);
    }
}
```

It's a pretty short class with only two functions. I'm cheating here as this class also extends from another class. But as written, this is backwards, so this class actually takes care of the recursion: `hasChildren` and `getChildren`. Obviously even those two functions don't have much code, they are just mapping the "question" (`hasChildren`? `getChildren`?) onto a standard `DOMNode`. If a node has children, well, say yes or just return them (and this is an iterator, return them in form of an iterator, hence the `new self()`).

So as this is pretty short, after choking it, just continue with the parent class `DOMIterator`  (the [`implements RecursiveIterator`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/RecursiveIterator) is just to make it working):

```
class DOMIterator extends IteratorDecoratorStub
{
    public function __construct($nodeOrNodes)
    {
        if ($nodeOrNodes instanceof DOMNode)
        {
            $nodeOrNodes = array($nodeOrNodes);
        }
        elseif ($nodeOrNodes instanceof DOMNodeList)
        {
            $nodeOrNodes = new IteratorIterator($nodeOrNodes);
        }
        if (is_array($nodeOrNodes))
        {
            $nodeOrNodes = new ArrayIterator($nodeOrNodes);
        }

        if (! $nodeOrNodes instanceof Iterator)
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Not an array, DOMNode or DOMNodeList given.');
        }

        parent::__construct($nodeOrNodes);
    }
}
```

This is the base iterator for [`DOMPHP`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), it just takes a [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/DOMNode) or a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/DOMNodeList) to iterate over. This sounds a bit superfluous maybe, as DOM supports this sort-of with `DOMNodeList` already, but it does not support a `RecursiveIterator` and we already know that we need one for `RecursiveTreeIterator` for the output. So in it's *constructor* an `Iterator` is created and passed on to the parent class, which again is abstract code. Sure I'll reveal this code in just a minute. As this is backwards, let's review what's been done so far:

- `RecursiveTreeIterator` for the tree-like output.
- `DOMRecursiveDecoratorStringAsCurrent` for the visualization of a `DOMNode` in the tree
- `DOMRecursiveIterator` and `DOMIterator` to iterate recursively over all nodes in a `DOMDocument`.

This in terms of definition as all that's needed, however the code that I called abstract is still missing. It's just some sort of simple proxy code, it delegates the same method down to another object. A related pattern is called *Decorator*. However, this is just the code, first the `Iterator` and then it's `RecursiveIterator` friend:

```
abstract class IteratorDecoratorStub implements OuterIterator
{
    private $iterator;
    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator)
    {
        $this->iterator = $iterator;
    }
    public function getInnerIterator()
    {
        return $this->iterator;
    }
    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->iterator->rewind();
    }
    public function valid()
    {
        return $this->iterator->valid();
    }
    public function current()
    {
        return $this->iterator->current();
    }
    public function key()
    {
        return $this->iterator->key();
    }
    public function next()
    {
        $this->iterator->next(); 
    }
}

abstract class RecursiveIteratorDecoratorStub extends IteratorDecoratorStub implements RecursiveIterator
{
    public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $iterator)
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return $this->getInnerIterator()->hasChildren();
    }
public function getChildren()
{
    return new static($this->getInnerIterator()->getChildren());
}
}
```

That's nothing very magically, it's just well delegating the method calls to it's inherited object `$iterator`. It looks like repeating and well iterators are about repetition. I put this into abstract classes so I only need to write this very simple code once. So at least I myself don't need to repeat myself.

These two abstract classes are used by other classes which have been already discussed earlier. Because they are so simple, I left it until here.

Well, much to read until here but the good part is, that's it.

In short: PHP does not have this build in, but you can write this on your own quite simple and re-useable. As written earlier, it's a good idea to wrap this into a function called `xmltree_dump` so it can be easily called for debugging purposes:

```
function xmltree_dump(DOMNode $node)
{
    $iterator = new DOMRecursiveIterator($node);
    $decorated = new DOMRecursiveDecoratorStringAsCurrent($iterator);
    $tree = new RecursiveTreeIterator($decorated);
    foreach($tree as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value . "\n";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>");
xmltree_dump($dom->documentElement);
```

the only thing needed is to have all the class definitions used included / required. You can put them in one file and use `require_once` or integrate them with an autoloader that you're probably using. [Full code at once](https://gist.github.com/1519893).

If you need to edit the way of output, you can edit `DOMRecursiveDecoratorStringAsCurrent` or change the configuration of `RecursiveTreeIterator­` inside `xmltree_dump`. Hope this is helpful (even quite lengthy, *backwards* is pretty in-direct).

Comment: +1 ....and you wrote all this on Christmas day as well. Achievement "Forever Alone" unlocked.

Comment: I'm getting `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to IteratorIterator::__construct() must implement interface Traversable, instance of DOMNodeList given` - what am I doing wrong? I grabbed the code from the gist and used the final example in the `usage` block at the bottom...

Comment: Sure, it should work, in which line exactly are you getting the error,? Is it for `$nodeOrNodes = new IteratorIterator($nodeOrNodes);` on [gist line 67](https://gist.github.com/1519893/a48f32aa58221de0953fcc458a573191a38cec88)?

Answer (score 15):

http://usphp.com/manual/en/function.dom-domdocument-savexml.php

```
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: And if wanting to debug a DOMElement that is not the document itself, but part of it: `$element->ownerDocument->saveXML($element));`.

Answer (score 10):

for a dom node, just use the following:

```
print_r(simplexml_import_dom($entry)->asXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tried it myself, check out [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), part of the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com). Documentation and examples for most of the Zend Framework components is really thorough.

Answer (score -1):

I just used DOMDocument::save.  It's lame that it has to write to a file, but whatever.

Comment: If you did that, you could just do saveHTML instead and have it go to a string.

Answer (score -1):

You can cheat and use JSON to inspect the structure by converting it to an array.

```
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($node), true));
```