# How to echo a DOMNodeList Object and a DOMElement Object?

Tags: php, dom

I am using a loop to populate an array called $list. it is working like a charm..

```
// $content is a DOMNodeList Object  
// $value is a DOMElement Object 

$list = array();

foreach ($content as $value){

    array_push($list, 'title'=>$value->nodeValue);  

}
```

Eventhough my loop is populating my array correctly, I would like to digg into that DOM thing a little more to understand things better (this DOM thing is to new to me...). So what I would like, is to see how the `DOMNodeList Object ($content)` and `DOMElement Object ($value)` looks like.

So my question is simple: how can I "echo-out" those 'elements'?

Comment: Check out [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug a DOMDocument Object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684227/debug-a-domdocument-object-in-php)

Comment: Hello Travelo. I already have firebug installed. How can i use it to check out how $content and $value "look like from inside"?

Comment: @Marc: You can't , I think Travesty3 has not read your question fully.

Comment: @eZakto: The point just is that `var_dump` does not offer much information about `DOMElement` or `DOMNodeList`.

Comment: Indeed, var_dump is just echoing " object(DOMNodeList)#7 (0) { } "... Nevertheless, the command given by Petr helped me see what I wanted to verify. Thanks to all for trying to help...

Comment: Ah whoops...dunno what I was thinking. For some reason, my mind went to JavaScript the second I saw DOM. I need some coffee or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better than "echo-out" DomElement, read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php.

If you want to see XML representation, use http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php,
i.e.

```
echo $value->c14N(false,true);
```

Comment: Thank you Petr. The command you gave me is working and thanks to it I manage to see what I wanted. Thanks :) I will in addition read the documentation...