# How to Debug seemingly empty DOM objects?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing, symfony-1.4

I am writing a task to import a XML. Debugging is a pain as both `var_dump` and `print_r` return seemingly empty objects for DOM objects like `DOMElement` and `DOMNodeList` list, looking so:

```
object(DOMElement)#330 (0) {}
object(DOMNodeList)#335 (0) {}
```

But they are not empty as I can read the values.

What debugging options have I instead?

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 5.4 and you will get more information, what you describe is only the case with the older PHP 5.3 version. See also [Debug a DOMDocument Object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684227/debug-a-domdocument-object-in-php) and [PHP XML how to output nice format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8615422/367456).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `DomDocument` I `var_dump` using the xml output.

```
var_dump($dom->saveXML());
```

For a `DOMElement`, I use ([as seen here](http://thisoldspoon.blogspot.fr/2009/08/dumping-domelement-in-php.html)):

```
var_dump($domElement->ownerDocument->saveXML($domElement));
```

But `DOMNodeList`, I have no idea. Maybe you have to attach/append it to a DomDocument, and then var_dump it.

And btw, not showing internals of a DomDocument is [reported (here: Reflection)](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48527).

Answer (score 1):

Solution: i wrote own monitoring function 'dom_test'

```
    function dom_test($DOM) {
      echo '<h1>'.get_class($DOM).'</h1>';
      // easiest way to traverse:
      echo 'LENGTH: '. @$DOM->length ."\n"; // if NodeList
      echo 'TAG: '. @$DOM->tagName ."\n"; // if Element
      echo 'CHILDS: '. @$DOM->childNodes->length ."\n"; // etc.
    }
```

hope this could help you!