# find all xml tagnames automatically in php

Tags: php, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname

I hope my questions isn't too dumb :)

What I want to do is to automatically list all different tagnames and attributes from a given xml document; from the first item for example. So that I can choose which ones I want to parse.

Example, for this xml:

```
<productItem id="123456">
    <name>laptop</name>
    <trackingLinks>
        <trackingLink>
            <ppc>http://xxxxxxxxx</ppc>
        </trackingLink>
    </trackingLinks>
    <description>laptop computer</description>
</productItem>
```

I should get a list of all tagnames/attributes like:

productItem>id

name

trackingLinks>trackingLink>ppc

description

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for all nodes that have no more children. You then list all their ancestor element nodes. Probably this can be easily done with xpath?

Comment: I'm not sure how...will this work without having to specify any tagname?

Comment: Yes that is possible (see as well: [Debug a DOMDocument Object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8631974/367456)), however your criteria contain some information that is not part of the XML. For example why isn't it  `productItem>trackingLinks>trackingLink>ppc`? Someone could argue there must be `productItem` at first, but in your question it's not there.