# how to get a raw from a DOMNodeList

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a `DomDocument`, which is impossible to `var_dump` (it really makes me angry) on which I do :

```
var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName('url'));
```

on a response like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
      <url>beaute-mode/cheveux/11460--choisir-un-headband</url>
      <title>get_url_article</title>
      <host>myhost</host>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

But I got the `var_dump` echoing : `object(DOMNodeList)[262]` instead of my raw data (which is an URL).

**So my question is pretty simple but how do I get my raw data without being encapsulated in an `DomNodeList` ?**

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DOMNodeList::item()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) will give a `DOMNode` in the `DOMNodeList` by index. For example, to get the first node in the list:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('url')->item(0)
```

To get the actual data that the element contains, use code something like this:

```
if ($node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('url')->item(0)) {
  $url = $node->nodeValue;
} else {
  // Element does not exist, handle error here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP itself - even as there were announced improvements with PHP 5.4 - is not that good in displaying structural information for `DomNode` and `DomNodeList`.

You can do something that I have outlined in a similar question [Debug a DOMDocument Object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684227/debug-a-domdocument-object-in-php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
DomTree::dump($doc->getElementsByTagName('url'));
```

Which will output the following:

```
`<url>
  `"beaute-mode/cheveux/11460--choisir-un-headband"
```

You can find the source-code in this [Gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/3449600).

Comment: Verry interesting answer, i'll bookmark your gist. PS : I'm using 5.4.6 and i don't see any differences between 5.3 with var_dump(DOMDocument)

Comment: I tested with PHP 5.4 now and I do not see them either. Looks like this needs more research and better understanding of the http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php : Version 5.3.11; 26-Apr-2012 : DOM - Added debug info handler to DOM objects.